# In Angular 1.6 is window load called before or after `transitions.onStart`?

Tags: angularjs, angular1.6

I need to call a function before the window load event fires. Is there another transition method I can call to guarantee my function is executed before the window load event fires?

Comment: Wherever you have your `angular.module()` code, (normally app.js) why not just put a function there?

Answer (score 1):

In Angularjs, you can use `.config` or `.run`methods attached to you module. They will execute before your controller.

From ngDoc : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/ce669edfa14dc7eb7c389d2f82c9c98399a9009b/docs/content/guide/module.ngdoc#LC122

> 1. **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration
>      phase. Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to
>      prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.
> 2. **Run blocks** - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the
>      application. Only instances and constants can be injected into run blocks. This is to prevent
>      further system configuration during application run time.

Usage :

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
       .config(function() {})
       .run(function() {});
```